# Spark: How to reduce the time to read files from S3?

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I need to read the JSON files present in S3 and process them. There are roughly 120,000 JSONL files present in a single directory of S3. Each file is roughly around 1.6MB in size.

My spark code is very simple:

```
spark.read().json(s3DirectoryPath)
```

This triggers two jobs:

1. List Job
2. Read Job

[image: List job]

My problem is that the list job takes a lot of time (roughly 2 hrs). How can I optimise this?

Also, I see that spark decided to form 10,000 tasks for listing files. How did Spark decide on the number of tasks? Can this be tuned to give better performance?

Note: Combining multiple files into large files is not an option for me.

Environment Details:

AWS EMR

2 Executors in 2 m5.xlarge machines

Comment: How many executors are running?

Comment: 2 executors. Increasing the executors is an option but I want to optimise this before I  beef up the underlying infrastructure.

Comment: You don't need more infra for more executors. You optimize with more executors. Say you have 16G of RAM on each node for example (m5.xlarge). Then you can run, say 3-4 executors with 3-4G each. Then if you have 2 spark workers, you can run 6-8 total executors, or even more with 1-2G GB per executor. Each file is less than 2MB, so you really don't need GB of memory

Comment: @OneCricketeer can you please let me know how to increase the number of executors? Also, how does spark arrive at the number 10000 tasks? Can I reduce that to optimise the read?

Comment: Have you seen the docs that say `--num-executors`? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: There's 100+k files, so one task is needed per file... You can optimize by Gzipping, or Bzip2-ing your JSON files in S3

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue before. Eventually, I listed all the files manually via `boto3` and put the string list into `spark.read.parquet`. This saved me tremendous amounts of time.